# PHP, formatting number by adding space every 4 numbers

Tags: php, formatting

I would like to separate every 4 numbers by space (starting backwards).

```
(example) From number: 1234567890, number: 12 3456 7890
```

number_format gives solution for separating by 3 numbers, is any method to do same for 4? There is way to separate by just iterating through string but im looking for most elegant solution.

Comment: From my point of view, a loop will be the est way. just wrap this into function for "elegance".

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), with a regex consisting of a lookbehind for a digit, and a lookahead for some multiple of 4 digits before the end of the number, and replace that zero-length match with a space:

```
$var = 1234567890;
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\d)(?=(\d{4})+$)/', ' ', $var);
```

Output:

```
12 3456 7890
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/apLFI)